# Nuxtjs not grabbing query params

Tags: javascript

I have the following url: `localhost:8080/account/reset-password?c=525448&g=usr&u=144c4c8e-5bf1-454f-a863-20c4ee149865` and am trying to grab the query parameters using Nuxtjs.

Within nuxt it seems like there is a $router object that can be used as `const queryParams = this.$route.query` but when I log out queryParams its an empty object.

I have also gone into the the browser console and tried

```
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
console.log(params) // returns Object {  }
```

what am I doing wrong? I would expect there to be an object

```
{
  c: 525448
  g: usr
  u: 144c4c8e-5bf1-454f-a863-20c4ee149865
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure where you're going wrong but for a start, applying those query params to THIS VERY PAGE and running your code snippet in the browser console does indeed give the object in your example, EXACTLY like in the example.

Comment: Nuxt does have access to the query parameters using `this.$route.query`, but only in certain lifecycle hooks. Could you provide a more complete example of how you're actually trying to get the query parameter IN NUXT?

Comment: Include in the example the hook you're calling the code in too.

Comment: @AlexScott that is probably my issue. is that the only place it works, in the hooks? im a bit of a Nuxt newb. that is probably my issue. I am trying to get the prams when a button is clicked.  I will update the code snippet

Comment: In theory you should be able to access the code your calling from anywhere, but if you include which hook you're calling the code in, then it can be tested and a potential solution found.

Comment: There are certain hooks where you can't access it using `this` and instead you need to use the context passed to the hook instead. @StillLearningToCode

Comment: If you're trying to get the query parameters in the `asyncData` hook for example, you can't use `this` and instead you access it using `asyncData({route})` or `asyncData({query})` as the context is passed to the hook as the first function argument. Either of these will work as `this.query` is an alias of `this.$route.query` in Nuxt.